# Access GrandChild of Multidimensional Array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array

I have a multi-dimensional array. It gets like `[["1","2","3"]]`, how can I access `"1"`?

To get more in detail...

```
lazy var data : [[NSURL]] = {

        var array = [[NSURL]]()

        if array.count == 0 {

            var index = 0
            var section = 0

            for image in images {
                if array.count <= section {
                    array.append([NSURL]())
                }
                array[section].append(image)

                index += 1

            }
        }
        return array
    }()
```

---

With `print(data)`, I can access:

```
[["firstUrl", "secondUrl", "thirdUrl"]]
```

How can I access `"first"`?

Comment: like that: `array[0][0]`

Comment: @AlexanderDoloz Add it as an answer and I accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this: `array[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

For example enumerate like this:

```
var dict = [["1","2","3"]]

for (index, item) in dict.enumerate() {
//hear you enumerate []
    for (index, item) in item.enumerate() {
        //hear you enumerate ["1","2","3"]
        print("Found \(item) at position \(index)")
    }
}
```